# How to reduce a random hash to a boolean value

Tags: c, ethereum

In c or a c-like language assuming I have a `random_hash` what is the cheapest way to reduce it to a boolean value i.e. `0` or `1`?

An example `random_hash` to normalise answers: `0x11bbe8db4e347b4e8c937c1c8370e4b5ed33adb3db69cbdb7a38e1e50b1b82fa`

Restrictions: no method/stdlib calls.

Why `c-like`, I'm actually trying to do it in  a language called [Solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Tutorial), which is modeled after `c/javascript`, which has a very limited runtime/stdlib.

Comment: I don't understand.. what is relation between the hash and the boolean?

Comment: Cheapest way? `return false;`

Comment: Assume that the hash is random, what I need is a boolean that represents that random value. I.e. if it were not a hash but a number like `82` and I knew it would never be higher than `100`  I could say `bool = (x <= 50) ? 0 : 1`

Comment: So you want to hash the hash into 1 bit hash? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the largest or smallest bit from the hash and use this as the boolean. Actually, taking any bit should be fine, assuming a good hash function. Assuming the hash is an array of unsigned char, you can use the bitwise AND operator `&`

```
(hash[0] & 1) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

In Solidity, you can use (as imallet also suggested)

`(value & 1) > 0`

assuming that `value` is of any `uintXX` or `bytesXX` type.
The `> 0` is important to convert the integer into a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the hash is truly random, the hash is represented as an array of bytes, and you want to do something like `bool = (x <= 50) ? 0 : 1`, you could do this:

```
bool = (hash[0] <= 127) ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: `hash[0] & 0x80 != 0` will produce the same.

Comment: It's half-range of char

Comment: @Christopher an unsigned char has values ranging from 0 - 255, so that's halfway between them.

Answer (score 0):

C-like:
`return (hash&1)>0;`